# How to access element present in Layout.cshtml in another page

Tags: javascript, background-color

I have two buttons in my `Layout.cshtml`, Index button and About button.

On start `index.cshtml` is displayed.

On clicking About button `About.cshtml` is displayed, on clicking 
back Index button `index.cshtml` is displayed.

What I want is when `index.cshtml` is displayed Index button should be of color Yellow.
And when `About.cshtml` is displayed About button should be of color Yellow.

How can i achieve this.

---

I using below logic to move to respective pages on button click

```html
<button id="Index" type="button" onclick="location.href='../Home/Index';">
<button id="About" type="button" onclick="location.href='../Home/About';">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try?

Comment: You can change the color of buttons base on URL.

Comment: <button id="Index" > and <button id="About" >are in Layout.cshtml. When I am in Index.cshtml page i want to use javascript and access these buttons by getelementbyID and then change their color. Is it possible to access html elements present in Layout.cshtml from Index.cshtml.